# Is there a mass-vs-radius chart for neutron stars?

Tags: neutron-star

I'm aware that we currently don't have an equation of state for the radius of a neutron star, because we don't know what happens to neutrons at their cores, and because the equations involved with neutron degenerate matter are horrendous. Is there enough data to make a chart of neutron stars as data points, with one axis being their masses, and the other being their radii?

Comment: See here, for example https://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C010815/docs/heiselberg.pdf Did you try searching something like "neutron star mass vs radius" on a search engine?

Comment: Yeah and all that came up was people looking for EOS's

Comment: Did you look at page two of the document I linked? Do you think the EOS matters here?

Comment: I meant EOS's were all that came up when I googled my question. This paper clearly has what I wanted. Thank you for linking it. Now all that's left is for me to figure out what all the acronyms are saying.